# .NET 6 - Webhook Receiver (Web API) - validate request client certificate with local client certificate

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, webhooks, x509certificate

I am currently using Starling Bank's Webhook to retrieve Feed API data, which I have been able to trigger on their Sandbox to send to a simple API I've put together.  I did check out the Microsoft documentation for [Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Custom](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Custom) but this doesn't appear to be designed for .NET 6 (I get a warning in VS against the dependency).  The simplest solution was to build a Web API which I could add the endpoint URL for in Starling's Sandbox.  As it stands, it works fine, triggering dummy payments, I am able to receive and insert into a SQL database.

Next step is to secure this using their public key, provided by them, to ensure the source of the client data, as recommended [here](https://developer.starlingbank.com/docs#ssl-pinning-1), under SSL Pinning.

I have tried a few different ways of retrieving the client certificate so I can compare to the local certificate, obtained from Starling, but none of the methods seem to get any certificate data.

This was one attempt, which returned a NULL result for `clientCert`:

```
 X509Certificate clientCert = Request.HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate;
 if (clientCert == null)
 {
     return Ok(new { status = "error" });
 }
 else
 {
     string localCert = "D:\\Certificate\\Starling\\starling-sandbox-api-certificate.crt";
     X509Certificate newCert = new X509Certificate(localCert);
     bool result = clientCert.Equals(newCert);                
     return Ok(new { status = "ok", cert = result.ToString() });
 }
```

I have also tried using:

```
string clientCert = Request.Headers["X_Client-Cert"];
```

but again this returns NULL.

How do I retrive the client certificate for validation?  I have been testing using Postman to send known good data, to debug the code to see what is being returned.  On stepping through the code in VS, `clientCert` is always NULL.

Please also note that I'm fairly new to .NET 6 and learning as I go along, so please excuse any obvious errors.

Comment: Could you spend some time to check the answer below, and if you need further help, pls  let me know.

Comment: Thanks @JasonPan I haven't had opportunity to return to this project yet but I will be shortly, I will let you know what happens

Answer (score 0):

```
X509Certificate clientCert = Request.HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate;
```

clientCert Always null, we should check the http request, before that, we need to check the `Client Certificates` in Postman like below.

[image]

**Steps**

1. Find the setting in postman.

[image]

2. Download the sandbox certificate and import it.

For more details, you can check the official bolg.

[Encryption, SSL/TLS, and Managing Your Certificates in Postman](https://blog.postman.com/encryption-ssl-tls-and-managing-your-certificates-in-postman/)